# App could not read static files in django

Tags: django

### medical_care/setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
    #os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static' ),
]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets') #it merge and put in the same directory
```

---

### medical_care/templates/index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title> Free Medical Hospital Website Template | Smarteyeapps.com</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static ' fav.jpg'%} ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static ' css/bootstrap.min.css'%}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static ' css/fontawsom-all.min.css '%} ">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static ' css/animate.css  '%}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static ' css/style.css '%} " />
```

---

### medical_care/hospital_app/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

---

### my directory:

```
medical_care/medical_care/
            /hospital_app/
            /static/images
                   /css
                   /js
            /templates/index.html
```

---

the error I have is

> GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/%20css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>   hospital:13 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/%20css/fontawsom-all.min.css%20 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
>   hospital:15 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/%20css/style.css%20 net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: There's a space after the quote in your url's can you remove that and check?

Comment: each of the string in your static tags don't need a space . example: `'css/bootstrap.min.css'`

Comment: Remove those spaces after / before your quotes and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static ' css/fontawsom-all.min.css '%} ">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static ' css/animate.css  '%}">
```

Those two lines contain extra two spaces. so modify those like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/fontawsom-all.min.css'%}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.css'%}">
```

Comment: There are still extra spaces in your "solution"